# combining two json strings without " or '

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have two JSON strings

String 1:

```
{"step":"example step", "data":"example data", "result":"example result"}
```

String 2:

```
{"attachments":[ { "data":"gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ", "filename":"example1.txt", "contentType":"plain/text" } ] }
```

I need both combined to that:
Expected Object:

```
{
   "step":"example step",
   "data":"example data",
   "result":"example result",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "data":"gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ",
         "filename":"example1.txt",
         "contentType":"plain/text"
      },
      {
         "data":"gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ",
         "filename":"example2.txt",
         "contentType":"plain/text"
      }
   ]
}
```

In every try the second string is getting ' or " around the array which will not work.

Comment: What did you actually try?

Comment: I have split it into several "phases"
So I have a method to build the attachment array and then I try to concat
String 1, static text ( ,  "attachments":[ ), the array elements, closing brackets ( ] } )

Comment: Without any tangible code that you have attempted yourself, it's impossible to actually debug what error you are actually getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manipulate them as strings – this will be fragile and very specific to the strings. Instead, parse the strings into dictionaries, do whatever manipulations you want, and then dump them back to JSON strings:

```
import json

s1 = '{"step":"example step", "data":"example data", "result":"example result"}'
s2 = '{"attachments":[ { "data":"gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ", "filename":"example1.txt", "contentType":"plain/text" } ] }'

d1 = json.loads(s1)
d2 = json.loads(s2)

d1.update(d2)

json.dumps(d1)
```

This will give you a clean json string:

```
'{"step": "example step", "data": "example data", "result": "example result", "attachments": [{"data": "gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ", "filename": "example1.txt", "contentType": "plain/text"}]}'
```

of if you want the object rather than the string, `d1` is now:

```
{'step': 'example step',
 'data': 'example data',
 'result': 'example result',
 'attachments': [{'data': 'gsddfgdsfg...(base64) ',
   'filename': 'example1.txt',
   'contentType': 'plain/text'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer, I'm updateing my code accordingly and will test it asap

Comment: In general your solution works, but I still have a problem with the s2 as this is getting still escaped.
The array is getting build in a dedicated method. The rest of s2 is getting added in another method.
I will need to make some more investigations on that